# SVM stats do MATLAB dá erro no teste

Tags: inteligência-artificial, matlab, aprendizagem-de-máquina

O seguinte código MATLAB faz o treino de um classificador binário do MATLAB dado um conjunto de vetores e testa outro conjunto de vetores nesse classificador:

```
%Número mínimo de iterações
optSVM = statset('MaxIter', 1000000);       

%treino do classificador
SVMtrainModel = svmtrain(training_vectors_matrix(:,2:end), training_vectors_matrix(:,1), 'kernel_function' ,  'linear', 'options', optSVM, 'tolkkt', 0.01);

%lê os vetores de teste 
TestV = csvread(test_file);

%Testa os vetores no classificador
TestAttribBin = svmclassify(SVMtrainModel, TestV(:,2:end))
```

Ou seja, é um código simples que rodaria sem problemas. Só que aqui o treino funciona normalmente, mas quando testo, o MATLAB me dá o seguinte erro:

```
Subscript indices must either be real  positive integers or logicals.

Error in svmclassify (line 140) 
outclass= glevels(outclass(~unClassified),:);
```

Qual seria a causa desse problema? Já procurei por valores NaN no treino e no teste e nada. Esse código rodaria normalmente em condições normais. O que tenho que pode estar causando isso?

<sub>Crosspost: [Matlab Stats Svm error in testing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23331276/1964435)</sub>

Comment: O que `TestV(:,2:end)` retorna? Pela descrição do erro parece que o código do SVM não está conseguindo filtrar os elementos em `TestV`. Tem como disponibilizar um exemplo funcional (incluindo os dados)? Dai eu posso testar por aqui.

Comment: Olá Luiz. Primeiramente obrigado pela resposta. TestV é uma matriz com os vetores de teste. Na primeira coluna de TestV eu tenho a classe real dos vetores (usadas posteriormente para calcular a acurácia) e, da segunda coluna em diante, temos os vetores de característica. Por isso TestAttribBin = svmclassify(SVMtrainModel, TestV(:,2:end)) testa os vetores de característica da matriz TestV no classificador binário SVMtrainModel. Vou disponibilizar os dados e fonte em alguns momentos. Mais uma vez obrigado.

Comment: Por nada @mad. Bom, desculpe se a pergunta for muito óbvia, mas você verificou se a dimensão dos vetores de características é a mesma nos dados de treinamento e de teste, né?

Comment: Oi Luiz. Esses mesmos vetores de características foram convertidos para o formato da Libsvm e na Libsvm está rodando normalmente a classificação. No entanto sua pergunta é muito boa portanto preciso checar. Mais uma vez obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

O AP conseguiu a [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23655800/221800):

Este deve ser solucionável mantendo minha solução genérica para este problema em mente.

1) Execute o código com dbstop se der erro

Ele agora vai parar na linha de que você forneceu:

```
outclass= glevels(outclass(~unClassified),:);
```

2) Verifique se as possíveis soluções.

Neste caso, eu assumo que `glevels` e `outclass` são as duas variáveis​​. A próxima coisa a fazer seria examinar cuidadosamente tudo o que poderia ser um índice.

De dentro para fora:

O primeiro índice é `~unClassified`, como a operação ~ não falhou, é seguro dizer que este é agora um vetor lógico.

O segundo e lastIndex é `outclass(~unClassified)`, é mais provável que não seja constituída apenas números como 1,2,3, ... ou valores verdadeiros/falsos deste.

O teste se os valores são todos válidos é bastante simples, um dos dois deve conter:

Para confirmar que os valores x são lógicas: `class(x)` deve retornar "lógica" 
Para confirmar que os valores x são reais inteiros positivos: `isequal(x, max(1,round(abs(x))))` deve retornar 'true'.